# Select not firing in GridView - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

I am having a issue with one of my pages in my ASP.NET Web Application - the computers.aspx page.

When clicking the select button on any of the records in 'GridView1' - Select doesn't fire. I have trawled througout roughly 20 related questions, but cannot find anything that works.

See Code Below:

```
     <div class="table-responsive" style="border:none">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged"  AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="idComputers" DataSourceID="ComputersGridview">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:Templatefield ShowHeader="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"  CausesValidation="true" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" commandname="select" Text="&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign&quot; style=&quot;font-size:x-large;font-align:center;color:rgb(34,54,104);&quot; /&gt;"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Templatefield><asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Select" Text="&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-check&quot; style=&quot;font-size:x-large;font-align:center;color:rgb(34,54,104);&quot; /&gt;"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Hostname" HeaderText="Hostname" SortExpression="Hostname" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" SortExpression="Username" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="officename" HeaderText="Office Name" SortExpression="officename" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IP Address" SortExpression="IPAddress" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="ManufacturerName" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="ManufacturerName" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="HDDSize" HeaderText="HDD Size" SortExpression="HDDSize" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="RAMSize" HeaderText="RAM Size" SortExpression="RAMSize" />
     </Columns>
                     <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ComputersGridView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ITManagementConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ITManagementConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT computers.idComputers, status.Status, computers.Hostname, ingenium.person.id, ingenium.person.forename, ingenium.person.surname, CASE WHEN ingenium.person.knownas = ' ' THEN concat(ingenium.person.forename, ' ', ingenium.person.surname) ELSE ingenium.person.knownas end AS Username, office.officename, computers.IPAddress, manufacturer.ManufacturerName, model.Model, harddrive.HDDSize, ram.RAMSize, Computers.DateCreated FROM computers INNER JOIN ingenium.person ON computers.idUser = ingenium.person.id INNER JOIN status ON computers.idStatus = status.idStatus INNER JOIN office ON computers.idoffice = office.idoffice INNER JOIN manufacturer ON computers.idManufacturer = manufacturer.idManufacturer INNER JOIN model ON computers.idModel = model.idModel INNER JOIN harddrive ON computers.idHDD = harddrive.idHardDrive INNER JOIN ram ON computers.idRAM = ram.idRAM WHERE (computers.idComputerType = 1) OR (computers.idComputerType = 2) ORDER BY computers.datecreated DESC">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

This was working yesterday - the Select has suddenly stopped firing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Many Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Did you add an UpdatePanel recently?

Comment: No, I don't use them

Comment: check your developer tool console

Comment: It's not showing any issue

Comment: Try altering CommandName to `Select` (capital 'S')

Comment: Does selecting a row at least fire a postback?  Do you get to the RowCommand event if you set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CausesValidation="False"` on both linkbuttons to see if problem is with validation. If it works like that, check your validation arguments.

Comment: Thanks for replying Sami - `CausesValidation = "False"` didn't work.

Comment: Does your event handler do anything else than just select the row? Could it be possible that the row does get selected but the style for selected row is exactly the same as for unselected row so you don't notice it?

Comment: It checks if the row is selected and highlights it red if it is - I explored that option early on as I thought that was the only issue, it then uncovered the issue with selection.

Comment: I was under the cosh at work over it, so I have restored it using a previous backup. The problem seems to have resolved itself, though I still have no idea of the original issue. Many thanks for your help on this Sami! Much appreciated.